# count the number of names according to gender and show top 10

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-analysis

I have a dataset like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["a"," b", "c","d", "e","a"," a", "a"," b", "c","d", "e","a"," a"],
               'gender': ["male", "female", "female", "female", "male","male","male","female","female", "female", "male","male","male"],
              'year':[2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2019, 2020],
              'month':[1, 12, 4, 3, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 1, 12, 4, 3, 6 ]
              'count':[100, 30, 10, 90,34, 100, 30, 10, 90,34, 100, 30, 10, 90,34, 36, 76]})
```

The dataset shows the name, gender, birth year and the birth month, and the number of people. For example, in 2005 January there were 100 babies named  “a”.
I want to find top-10 frequent names for males and females. just as below:
[image]

I tried this code

```
data.groupby('name','gender')['count'].count().nlargest(10)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df.groupby(['gender','name'])['count'].count().nlargest(10)
```

When using `groupby` to group against multiple columns, you should use list of columns names rather than passing them as arguments to the function.

Also, PS, your sample data is horribly constructed, each column is having different number of data points and the names/genders are very inconsistent.